# How to capture screenshot event on IOS with React Native

Tags: react-native

How to capture screenshot event on IOS with React Native? I need to warn user about the screenshot action, for example, pop up some alert information when screenshot action detected. Need some tips here. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet, Daniel?